# Why is %systemd_post, used in the spec-file, not enabling or starting the service after installation?

Tags: fedora, systemd, rpmbuild

I'm having a very simple unit-file which comes with a service which I package to a RPM-file. This RPM-file is built and installed on Fedora 28.

My service-file could not be simpler:

```
[Unit]
Description=Hello Work

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/executable

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

In my spec file I added these sections:

```
%post
%systemd_post %{name}.service

%preun
%systemd_preun %{name}.service

%postun
%systemd_postun_with_restart %{name}.service
```

The service file is copied correctly via

```
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{_unitdir}/
cp %{name}.service %{buildroot}%{_unitdir}/
```

in the `%install`-section.

When I install the package, the service is not started. When I run manually

```
systemctl enable <service-name>
```

it works.

Where is my mistake that the installation does not enable and start my service?

Answer (score 2):

When looking at the [documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/#_scriptlets), it does not say that `%systemd_post` starts your service. They refer to [systemd.preset](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.preset.html): you need to define and package a `%{name}.preset` file that specifies that your service should be enabled by default.

This should **enable** your package by default.

I'm not entirely sure that now your package will be **started** by default, but it looks like it :)

Comment: In the meantime I found that they are quite explicit actually, when reading the documentation until the end: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Systemd#Why_don.27t_we....  Services are not started by default for multiple reasons.